# Materialize Datepicker wrong height

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, materialize

anyone know how to resize and hide overflow-y in Materialize Datepicker. I am using ASP with MVC 4.0. Looks like is getting parent div settings.

[image]

Thanks

Edit: I moved datepicker input outside of any div in the view without success, i am trying to find the month days container class to do tests.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem here was a styled tbody used in a custom css, the days container is in a tbody.

PD: I used mozilla firefox to debug webpage elements.